# systick eqvivalent in pre cortex arms

Tags: atmel, arm7

I'm building a library for at91sam7x, wich is a arm7.

I need a delay timer, but there is no systick, i found several mentions of system timer but nothing usefull.

Is there a way to generate delay, or periodic functions without using built-in timers?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a built-in timer?? You mention systick, which *is* a built-in timer on Cortex chip.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen It's an arm7 it's pre Cortex architecture.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was wondering why you don't want to use a built-in timer, as you metion systick as something you'd want to use, which *does* use a built-in timer.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen It's because most timers were taken by my colegues library, and the rest was used for main. At 1:00 in morning i couldn't think of anything, later I've decided to use timer with function pointer stack. Reading my question now, what was i thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find there are lots of timers in your microcontroller, any one of which can generate an interrupt.

On processors where the core doesn't have a dedicated tick timer this is the standard way to generate your basic timing interrupt.

Chose the simplest timer which does what you want - then you will probably need to:

- Power up the timer
- Enable the timer's clock
- Configure the timer
- Enable interrupts on the timer
- Enable the appropriate IRQ on the micro's interrupt routing and
- Enable interrupts globally on the core.

This is generic list of steps which may or may not all be needed on the SAM7, but are typical for this class of micro.

Answer (score 0):

The AT91sam7x has both a "Periodic Interval Timer (PIT)" as well as a "Real-time Timer (RTT)" as well as a "Three-channel 16-bit Timer/Counter". So there's plenty of timers that can generate an interrupt whenever you need one.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to generate delay, or periodic functions without using built-in timers?

Yes - you can count loop cycles, if the execution time is more or less predictable.

You can also utilize an external counter and uses its output to interrupt the mcu.

alternatively, you can use timers, or compare match, or pwm capabilities as as a timing device.